# Unity - 2D physics omissions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, geometry

I'm having trouble finding some pretty simple things with the new 2D Unity functions!

Firstly, am I right in thinking that `rigidBody2D` doesn't have a `position` variable like it's three-dimensional bigger brother? It was my understanding I should be using the `rigidBody` positions, not `transform.position` as this is in `FixedUpdate` - so what am I supposed to do?

Secondly, I can't access the `CircleCollider2D.radius` variable despite being listed in the documentation, and above this I can't even access `gameOject.circleCollider2D` or `gameObject.collider2D.circleCollider2D` in code (C#).

Am I going mad, Am I missing something, or is Unity missing something? =/

Cheers for any help anyone can give on this, even if it's to confirm something.

Comment: Unity answer site might help you more http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html

Answer (score 2):

if your game object has CircleCollider2d then, you will get circlecollider2d as follow.

1>  Declare a variable for CircleCollider2d.

```
 CircleCollider2d c_collider2d;
  c_collider2d = gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2d>();
  c_collider2d.radius = 1.5f;//set radius value for collider.
```

RigidBody don't have position values, it always follow the game object where it is attached.